# canvg conversion fail image cutoff

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, svg, raphael

So I am trying to convert the raphael svg I have to the canvas using the canvg js lib and when I do the conversion the images that I have that fill some of the raphael elements end up getting cut up and moved to certain places within the raphael element after the svg conversion is complete. Check out the pictures below.

[image: SVG Before]

[image: Canvg Conversion After]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the creator of canvg he determined that there was a small bug that needed to be fixed within his script. He fixed it and now this is not an issue. Just make sure you grab the latest version of canvg for the fix.